# Cricket match algorithm

Tags: algorithm, workflow

I need to create a cricket manger game (much like football manger).

Long story short i need to decide the outcome of a game based on each users team and tactics. My idea was to decide the outcome ball by ball.

So depending on a Bowlers attributes (strength, stamina, skill etc) a ball (with some properties : speed etc) is send towards the batsmen, the batsmen would hit (or not) the ball depending on a score too, if the ball is hit i would then send the ball towards one of the fielders (assume there are 9, generate a random number between 1 and 9 and pass the that fielder). Again based on fielder skill it would catch the ball or not.

What I'm missing is the number of runs the the batsmen would do before the ball is catched.
I want to fine tune the direction of the ball.
I'm also not sure how order of player entrance would affect the game outcome.

Can you help me define a good match workflow ? ( I'm not very familiar with a cricket, read tutorials, watched games, never played though).

Thank you.

Update:

I'm also thinking to that a ball would store most of the decision data need, e.g:

ball.**Bowler** = player (the bowler who threw the ball)

ball.**Batsmen** = player (the batsmen who might hit it)

ball.**OverId** = in which over this ball was played

ball.**Hittable** = 4 (the number would be probably generated from the bowler strengt + others, also it might be dependent on Bowler and Batsmen

ball.**Runs** = 2 the number the runs made by the batsmen who hit the ball

ball.IsUsed whenever the ball is worn out or new
ball.IsOutside = true if the ball was send outside the field

===== Would be used to calculate if the batsmen can bat this ball or not

ball.**ThrowHeight**

ball.**ThrowSpeed**

ball.**ThrowEffect**

ball.**ThrowNumberOfBounces**

ball.**BattedHeight**

ball.**BattedSpeed**

ball.**FieldlerDirection** = **3** (towards  the third fieldler), random

ball.**FieldlerDirectionOffset** = **2** (in the 2 meter range of the 3rd fieldler. 0 would be that the fielder might catch it directly from mid air, ), random

And i also need to consider if the bowler shoots for the stumps, this would be another workflow..

**Update2:**

The competition is 20/20 cricket.

Comment: are you going to model changing the fielders' positions on the field, like a real team captain does?  In any event, a good batsman plays the ball towards where there _are no fielders_....

Comment: If the ball is caught the batsman scores no runs; any runs that the batsmen may have made before the catch are discounted.

Comment: This seems more like a cricket question than a programming question.

Comment: You need to treat spin and pace bowlers separately. You also need to take the condition of the pitch into account, as this will determine how much bounce and "turn" there is on a ball, which will in turn determine how effective a given bowler may be.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Only if it's caught without bouncing, yes? Otherwise, most batted balls end up being caught, sooner or later.

Comment: @Alnitak, yes a tactic would be the order of player entrance, although I'm not sure how this would affect the game outcome

Comment: @Zapacila it surely does, otherwise real teams wouldn't send out their best players first, and their wicket keepers last.

Comment: @Alnitak, i agree but i don't see how i should integrate it in the outcome alg, maybe it boosts the morale of the team or something like that..

Comment: Number of runs would be calculated based on player speed, and time until the ball is caught , so i need first to determine the time spent to catch the ball, my first idea is to measure distance from the nearest fielder to where the ball is dropped (2 seconds until ball can be caught in mid air, plus the time until the nearest fielder reaches the ball in case he doesn't directly caches it, say like 5 meters away),

Comment: now having the distance and the average fielder speed i can find out the the spent, and using this time i can determine how many runs the batsmen did using his speed, and of course this would take in consideration is ball was outside field or if it's directly caught

Comment: @Zapacila Batting order affects the outcome in several ways, depending on the format. Test openers have to be supremely steady and calm, big hitters usually come in the middle order, then your all-rounders and finally your specialist bowlers. Steady partnerships are another key factor, how new the ball is, how many overs are left in the day (nightwatchmen) and so on. Limited overs cricket is somewhat more straightforward, you must put your big hitters fairly high in the order, otherwise you run the risk of them not even getting to bat.

Comment: @bizclop, Thanks for your input, one question tough why would they risk not to bat ? (Fairly newbie at cricket)

Comment: @Zapacila In limited overs cricket (as the name suggests), they play a fixed amount of overs (50, 40 or 20 in T20), so if the overs run out before it's your turn, you don't get to bat.

Comment: By the way, I've only got into cricket a couple of years ago myself and I found what helps is listen to and read the analysis during or after matches. Cricket is an incredibly complex game (on the level of detail you need to simulate it accurately) but it is also very well researched and documented.

Comment: Well i guess everyone would put their best batters at first why wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, the question is what do you mean by "best". In T20 you need batsmen who are strong and can whack the ball hard. What you don't need is Steady Eddies, who waste precious deliveries with blocking and prodding. Even though the same Steady Eddies are invaluable in test cricket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, but I don't see the utility of this. Are you making a simulation?

In any case, if I were in your position, I would have done the following for each ball, assuming you have all the relevant data corresponding to the players.

I would break this into 4 stages and each outcome is defined by

**a. Strategy**

**b. Strength**

**c. Randomness**

**d. State of previous stages.**

1. Define the fielding positions. According to the bowling team strategies, I would place my strong fielders in the critical [positions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fielding_%28cricket%29). This could be done by a mix of strategy and some randomness.
2. Define the ball. This would depend upon the bowler's skill (spinner/fast bowler/swing bowler), match situations(yorkers at the end of the innings etc), some random factors, and some rules(one bouncer per over etc)(See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowling_%28cricket%29)). The result of this stage is a perfectly defined ball position/speed/orientation near the batsman (basically the trajectory).
3. Define the stroke. This would depend upon the batsman's strength, match situations, some randomness and most importantly the definition of the ball from stage 2 (See [here])[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batting_%28cricket%29). This would define the next trajectory/ speed.
4. Define the fielding. This is the most crucial for you w.r.t your question. Now this depends upon the field placements as per stage 1, fielder strength,  and most crucially the definition of the ball trajectory from stage 3. Depending upon these factors, it could be a catch, or 0,1,2,4,6 runs. Some obvious implementations could be that if the position of the ball is almost bisecting two fielders and no other fieleders are nearby and if the speed of the ball is good enough to reach the boundary, it is 4 runs. Here you will have to implement the physics of the ball trajectory properly in stage 4. Not only this, if the trajectory is without touching the ground and if there is a player nearby this could be defined as a catch, if the ball has already touched the ground before reaching near the player, you could modify the trajectory to guide the ball back to the wicket keeper etc. Maybe you could implement simple rules here before getting into difficult situations such as run outs.

Finally the ball is supposed to reach back to the bowler.

All the best.

Comment: Well i need to simulate it so i can find who wins, also in a later stage i would like comments that's why i need the game to be as real as possible. In the meantime you wrote this i also updated the question which incorporates some of your ideas i think.

Comment: Problem is that in the first stage i would like to keep it simple, but very extensible. I agree with the direction of the ball should be between fielders, and the nearest should try to catch it (with randomness factor). From the distance and fieldler speed i can get the time necessary to catch and return the ball to the bowler and from this i can extract the number of runs the batsmen did assuming a batsmen can do lets say 6 runs per minute.

Comment: Well, you could also make it more precise since the length of the pitch is always 22yards. So, if you define the batsman speed to be pre-configured quantity, you could equate the length/speed to the amount of time taken by the ball to come back to solve get the number of runs more precisely. Anyway, as you mentioned this is getting more to the precise physics which you may not need initially

Comment: like I said, `ETOOMANYVARIABLES` ;-)

Comment: Even i don't like it very much, the need of simple physics might be needed. So to make it a bit simpler, I'll probably make the following assumptions : the bowlers always catch the balls sent from the fielders and always in the same fixed time. (in the first phase)

Comment: @Alnitak agreed, but cricket is a complex game, and if i don't simulate at least some basic the users won't feel that they are playing it, although is just numbers, the outcome should be close to real. I'm opened to suggestions of making this simpler..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a physical simulation of cricket is a good idea in general. If I were you, I'd try to tackle the problem on a more abstract level.

Bowling:

1. Speed, length and line. This depends on tactics and how consistent the bowler is.
2. Swing or spin. This depends on bowling technique, the pitch and the weather.
3. Mistakes: no-balls or wides. This depends on bowler consistency again.

Once you know what type of delivery was made (yorker, bouncer, full toss, googly, whatever), you can play a similar game from the batsman's point of view: does he try to hit it, block it or leave it? Does he prefer playing off the front foot or back foot? And so on.

You get the idea: the outcome should be calculated from player and environmental attributes directly, using the concepts already established in cricket analysis.

As a bonus, you can use D-L to validate that your algorithm is realistic.

Comment: That's the way i want to do it, but i still need to "simulate" a game ball by ball although all I'm doing is to simulate numbers per actions, compare than and see outcome.

Comment: @Zapacila Yes, that's the general idea. Still ball by ball, but not a physical simulation. Once you determined the exact outcome, you can adjust the graphics to fit it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duckworth%E2%80%93Lewis_method As you can see, an awful lot of scientific research has gone into cricket already, on which you can rely in your simulation. You don't have to invent everything yourself.

Comment: Yes but than i won't be able to add per ball comments, also i won't be able to introduce new variables and or balance the game.. later on things like weather, team morale, audience stuff like that will influence the game result. I'm will not probably be able to modify those mathematical models to fit these changes or whatever changes the client would want, that's why i try as much as possible not to rely on "magic" formulas for game outcome. Plus I'm not that great at statistics either, but thank you for your input I'll try to study D/L

Comment: @Zapacila I think you misunderstand me. You should definitely do ball-by-ball simulation. Just not a physical simulation with angles and distances, but rather something relying on abstract concepts, like line, length, swing and so on. D/L is just a way to test whether your simulation is realistic. You run a 1000 simulations batch and look at the outcomes, compare it with what D/L would predict.

Comment: Oh yes, definitely very simple calculation. Thank you!